# Run code configuration not showing up in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

So, I wanted to run a program in c, but after installing code runner, I find the program running in output. I found the solution i.e. to go to run code configuration in settings. But I found that the run code configuration option is missing.

I tried a few things but all were in vain. Kindly help me please.

Answer (score -2):

The "Run Code configuration" settings entry shows up after installing the extension "Code Runner".

Comment: How can you check if the extension is missing? What should be done to solve the issue? Your answer would benefit from additional details

Comment: this answer essentially seems to amount to "it works fine for me", which is not very useful at all on its own as an answer post. (why does it work for you but not the asker? what't the environmental difference?) it would be fine as a comment, but an answer should have some real substance to it.